# Morphological Analyzer for Hindi and English in Python

Tags: nlp

I am unable to find morphological analyzers for English or Hindi. I am looking for a tool that can split the word into morphemeses e.g.

Independently = In + dependent + ly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the ploygot package which can perform [morphological analysis](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MorphologicalAnalysis.html) in English and Hindi.

```py
from polyglot.text import Word

word = Word("Independently", language="en")
print(word, w.morphemes)
```